# I have keys, but no locks and rooms

Tags: riddle, locks

I have keys, but no locks and rooms. You can enter, but you can't go outside. What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?